# splitting the lines in a file and compare the array element

Tags: c

I have written the following code to split the lines, in which the strings are separated by symbol '@', and storing in the array named as'buf' here. This code is working fine if I am comparing any string present in the array[0] . but If I try to find the string present in array[3] for example here as 'admin', then it is having error as 'segmentation fault' . Could anyone help me to find why this code is not comparing any other argument.
I would be very thankful for this.

```
char **strsplit(const char* str, const char* delim, size_t* numtokens) {
    char *s = strdup(str);
    size_t tokens_alloc = 1;
    size_t tokens_used = 0;
    char **tokens = calloc(tokens_alloc, sizeof(char*));
    char *token, *rest = s;
    while ((token = strsep(&rest, delim)) != NULL) {
        if (tokens_used == tokens_alloc) {
            tokens_alloc *= 2;
            tokens = realloc(tokens, tokens_alloc * sizeof(char*));
        }
        tokens[tokens_used++] = strdup(token);
    }
    if (tokens_used == 0) {
        free(tokens);
        tokens = NULL;
    } else {
        tokens = realloc(tokens, tokens_used * sizeof(char*));
    }
    *numtokens = tokens_used;
    free(s);
    return tokens;
}
```

The main() is as follows:

```
    int main(void) {
char *line = NULL;
size_t linelen;
char **tokens;
size_t numtokens;
int ret=1;
FILE *ptr_file;
char buf[1000];
system("rm -rf input1.txt");
system("/www/stest/mds1 > input1.txt");
ptr_file =fopen("/www/stest/input1.txt","r");
if (!ptr_file)
 return 1;
while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
{

     tokens = strsplit(buf, "@\n", &numtokens);
     size_t i;
    for ( i = 0; i < numtokens; i++)
       {
         ret=strcmp(tokens[3],"member");
         if(ret==0)
           {

             printf("%s",buf);

             break;
           }
        }
    fclose(ptr_file);
     return 0;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Here is the output of the above code and I am having error if I want to print the lines which has 'member'as the third argument of the array.

```
    abc@google.com@abdu@admin
    abc@rediff.com@savya@cashier
    abc@yahoo.com.com@andy@member
    abc@google.com@susan@group
    abc@facebook.com@andre@admin
```

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your problem might be in how you're setting up the array. You should probably post that code.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `strsplit` function.  I compiled and tested it (with my own `main` function, before you posted yours) and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Minor: `fgets(buf,100, ptr_file)` but you defined `char buf[1000];`

Comment: It's odd to be looping for `i` from 0 to `numtokens`, but then inside the loop always comparing to `tokens[0]`.

Comment: sorry , there were some mistakes which I fixed  now. Thanks for the help . I changed the number from 100 to 1000, but it is still having error if I am trying to print the line,    ret=strcmp(tokens[3],"member");

Comment: Can you show your updated main?

Comment: You are assuming that you read a line that has at least 4 tokens.  Are you sure you are parsing the line with that many?

Comment: now I updated the main() , changed the argument value to compare but it is showing error as 'segmentation fault. Please help me to edit the code so that I could get the desired result, as it is printing for 'ret=strcmp(tokens[0],"abc"). Thanks

Comment: The code is updated, but as @SteveSummit commented, in `main` what is the point of the `i` loop when you always compare with `token[3]`? And what will happen when there are fewer than 4 tokens found?

Comment: Yes , all the lines in the file are having four tokens exactly, which are separated by '@'

Comment: To reinforce Steve's point, `i` is not used in the loop.

Comment: I am lost , so pls help me to modify the code.

Comment: I would like to run the code but my compiler does not have `strsep` ;(

Comment: Are there any other white space characters before the newline such as '\r'?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you want is something like this:

```
tokens = strsplit(buf, "@\n", &numtokens);
if(numtokens >= 4 && strcmp(tokens[3],"member") == 0)
    {
    printf("%s",buf);
    }
```

As shown in George Houpis's answer it would also be good to double-check that `strsplit` does not return a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but the comment is not big enough.  If you run this as your main, what is the output?

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    FILE * fin = fopen( "/www/stest/input1.txt", "rt" );
    if( !fin )
        return 1;
    char buffer[1000];
    while( fgets( buffer, 1000, fin ) )
    {
        size_t token_count;
        char ** tokens = strsplit( buffer, "@\n", &token_count );
        if( tokens )
        {
            size_t index;
            for( index = 0; index < token_count; ++index )
                if( !strcmp( tokens[index], "member" ) )
                    printf( "%d: %s  | %s", index, tokens[index], buffer );
            for( index = 0; index < token_count; ++index )
                free( tokens[index] );
            free( tokens );
        }
    }
    fclose( fin );
    return 0;
}
```

When I run with those 5 lines in the text file, I get:

```
3: member  |     abc@yahoo.com.com@andy@member
```

EDIT:

You can tokenize the string without malloc by keeping a second buffer and using pointers to that (still uses memory on the stack).

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    FILE * fin = fopen( argv[1], "rt" );
    if( !fin )
        return 1;
    char buffer[1000];
    while( fgets( buffer, 1000, fin ) )
    {
        char buffer_copy[1000];
        strcpy( buffer_copy, buffer );
        char * tokens[1000];
        size_t token_count = 0;
        char * ptr = tokens[token_count] = buffer_copy;
        while( *ptr )
            if( ( *ptr == '@' ) || ( *ptr == '\n' ) )
                *ptr++ = '\0', tokens[++token_count] = ptr;
            else
                ++ptr;

        size_t index;
        for( index = 0; index < token_count; ++index )
             if( !strcmp( tokens[index], "member" ) )
                 printf( "%d: %s  | %s", index, tokens[index], buffer );
    }
    fclose( fin );
    return 0;
}
```

If you go with fixed position (always 3rd (0 indexed)), you can just scan and check:

```
int is_member( const char * buffer )
{
    if( !buffer )
        return 0;

    size_t index;
    const char * ptr = buffer;
    for( index = 0; index < 3; ++index, ++ptr )
        if( !( ptr = strchr( ptr, '@' ) ) )
            return 0;
    return !strncmp( ptr, "member", 6 ) && ( ( *( ptr + 7 ) == 0 ) || ( *( ptr + 7 ) == '@' ) || ( *( ptr + 7 ) == '\n' ) );
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    FILE * fin = fopen( argv[1], "rt" );
    if( !fin )
        return 1;
    char buffer[1000];
    while( fgets( buffer, 1000, fin ) )
        if( is_member( buffer ) )
             printf( "%s", buffer );
    fclose( fin );
    return 0;
}
```

Or if the position is not known, then you can find each token on the fly.  This takes no significant additional memory (a couple pointers) and does not modify your buffer:

```
int is_member( const char * buffer, const char * delimiters )
{
    size_t index;
    const char * ptr = buffer, * eptr = buffer;
    for( ; eptr; ptr = eptr + 1 )
        // If the next delimiter is found and it is 6 characters away or not found, and the substring matches 'member', return 1.
        if( ( !( eptr = strpbrk( ptr, delimiters ) ) || ( eptr - ptr == 6 ) ) &&
            !strncmp( ptr, "member", 6 ) )
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    FILE * fin = fopen( argv[1], "rt" );
    if( !fin )
        return 1;
    char buffer[1000];
    while( fgets( buffer, 1000, fin ) )
        if( is_member( buffer, "@\n" ) )
             printf( "%s", buffer );
    fclose( fin );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can anyone suggest me how to split the  buffer containing the same elements as in input.txt file and without using malloc()

Comment: Keep an array of pointers and modify the search buffer for the delimiter and overwrite it with a null '\0' character.

Comment: I used array of pointers but I am filtering the lines where first token = "abc", so I used if(token[0] == "abc") print "token[i]", but it is not printing the complete lines rather itis printing only the first token. so, can anyone help me how to do that.,

Answer (score 0):

I did it it without  using file * since I have the buffer already. It is working. thanks.

```
char buffer_copy[1000];
    strcpy( buffer_copy, buffer );
    char * tokens[1000];
    size_t token_count = 0;
    char * ptr = tokens[token_count] = buffer_copy;
    while( *ptr )
        if( ( *ptr == '@' ) || ( *ptr == '\n' ) )
            *ptr++ = '\0', tokens[++token_count] = ptr;
        else
            ++ptr;

    size_t index;
    for( index = 0; index < token_count; ++index )
         if( !strcmp( tokens[index], "member" ) )
             printf( "%d: %s  | %s", index, tokens[index], buffer );
```